# How can I change button object color?

Tags: javascript, button

I have been trying to debug my javascript button object's mouseover function. What I am trying to create, is a function call (in this case show()) within the object that will listen for the mouseover event and change the object's button color to grey. I think the problem is that the btnColor is not updating the original show() call, but I am not sure how to remedy this. What am I missing?

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("JScanvas");
let c = canvas.getContext("2d");
let mousePosition = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

// ignore, a few functions I might need for this to run

function buildRect(fillColor, outlineColor, outlineSize, x, y, w, h) {

  if (fillColor && outlineColor) {
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(x, y, w, h);
    c.fillStyle = fillColor;
    c.fill();
    c.lineWidth = outlineSize;
    c.strokeStyle = outlineColor;
    c.stroke();
  } else if (fillColor && !outlineColor) {
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(x, y, w, h);
    c.fillStyle = fillColor;
    c.fill();
  } else if (!fillColor && outlineColor) {
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(x, y, w, h);
    c.lineWidth = outlineSize;
    c.strokeStyle = outlineColor;
    c.stroke();
  }
}

function write(str, x, y, color, txtSize, font) {
  let size = txtSize.toString();
  c.font = size + "px" + " " + font;
  c.fillStyle = color;
  c.fillText(str, x, y);

}
// end of useless functions

class button {
  // mouse is {canvs: canvas, mClicked: t/f, mPosition: mousePosition{x, y}}
  constructor(name, order, btnColor, x, y, w, h, txtColor, txtSize, m, f) {
    this.name = name;
    this.order = order;
    this.btnColor = btnColor;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.txtColor = txtColor;
    this.txtSize = txtSize;
    this.m = m;
    this.f = f;
  }

  show() {
    //***This is the problem area***
    // :(
    //change color when mouse over button...at least ideally... 
    this.m.canvs.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
      console.log("hello there");
      /*if(this.x < this.m.mPosition.x && this.m.mPosition.x < this.x + this.w && this.y < this.m.mPosition.y && this.m.mPosition.y < this.y + this.h)
       */
      this.btnColor[0] = "grey";
    }); // end of problem area
    console.log(this.btnColor);
    if (!this.btnColor[0] && !this.btnColor[0]) {

      buildRect("transparent", false, 1, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    } else if (!this.btnColor[0]) {

      buildRect(false, this.btnColor[1], 1, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    } else if (!this.btnColor[1]) {

      buildRect(this.btnColor[0], false, 1, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    } else {
      buildRect(this.btnColor[0], this.btnColor[1], 1, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);

    }
    c.fillStyle = this.txtColor;
    let theString = String(this.txtSize) + "px Arial";
    c.font = theString;
    let width = Math.round(c.measureText(c.fillText(this.name, -1000, 0)).width);

    if (width > this.w) {
      let center = this.x + (this.w / 2);
      let newSize = this.w / width;
      c.font = String(this.txtSize * newSize);
      let newWidth = Math.round(newSize * width);
      c.textAlign = "center";
      c.textBaseline = "middle";
      c.fillText(this.name, this.x + (this.w / 2), this.y + (this.h / 2));

    } else {
      c.textAlign = "center";
      c.textBaseline = "middle";
      c.fillText(this.name, this.x + (this.w / 2), this.y + (this.h / 2));
    }
  }

  clickButton(mouseX, mouseY) {
    if (mouseX >= this.x && mouseX <= this.x + this.w && mouseY >= this.y && mouseY <= this.y + this.h) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  runf() {
    this.f();
  }
}

//getting mouse position 

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (evt) => {
  let r = getMousePos(canvas, event);
  mousePosition.x = r.x, mousePosition.y = r.y;
});

let mouse = {
  canvs: canvas,
  mClicked: false,
  mPosition: mousePosition
};

//button object to call: ("red" is the color of the button I am trying to change to grey)
let cookie = new button("cookie", 1, ["red", false], 50, 100, 150, 50, "black", 30, mouse, 2);
cookie.show();
```

```html
<div id="JScanvas"></div>
```

Comment: Well, you're only setting an instance variable, not redrawing anything on your canvas.

Comment: @isherwood Appreciate the suggestions. I also just made sure the code can be easily run from a single html script.

Comment: @AKX I was thinking that was the problem. Does javascript not re-run the function or loop back through the script? If it does, then the object should be re-run with the updated color (At least that's what I think).

Comment: No worries. Be sure to take the [tour] for more tips. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Just call this.show after the btnColor[0] change, this will redraw the button with the new color:

```
   if(this.btnColor[0] != "grey"){
      this.btnColor[0] = "grey";
      this.show();
   }
```

But you should put the addEventListener block in the constructor! Because we only want to add the event listener once.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I have thought of that as well, but the problem with calling show() each time the mouse is detected, is that a whole new button is created (This eventually crashed my browser). Placing the event listener in the constructor has the same effect. Do you know if there is anyway to change the original show() call or only create the grey button once?

Comment: Yes, I updated the code in my answer.  Only call the show if the btnColor[0] is not already grey.

Comment: Works like a champ! Appreciate your help. Right now it will cover the first instance of show() with another grey button. That's not a big deal, but would you know if there was a way to only have one button up at all times?

Comment: You initially create the button with red color, so the first instance is red. Thats why it is drawn with red, and if the mouse move also with grey once.  " if there was a way to only have one button up at all times?" it is only one button, you just refreshing the graphics, but technically you have only one button.